# Contravariant metric tensor with off-diagonal terms

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I have to compute the contravariant metric tensor with off-diagonal terms, such as $g_{0i}\neq 0$. I started with the condition $$g_{\mu\nu}g^{\nu\lambda}=\delta^\lambda_\mu$$
but I don't know how to proceed. I can write
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
g_{00}g^{00}+g_{0i}g^{i0}=1\\
g_{i0}g^{0j}+g_{ik}g^{kj}=\delta^j_i\\
\end{array}
\right.$$
but I have 3 unknowns with 2 equations. How can I find the contravariant components?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to find them? What information do you already have, and what is your goal to achieve with that?

Comment: I have this metric and I need to find the inverse, but since it is not diagonal I can't invert the term on the diagonal, the paper I'm reading suggests to use the condition i wrote.

Comment: Is this really that much different from calculating the inverse of a matrix in linear algebra? It's quite a standard procedure.

Comment: But I don't know how to do it since the metric is expanded up to second order and the expression is not so easy

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. Can you not use Cramer's rule or Gaussian elimination to find the inverse? Of course things can get quite messy for $4 \times 4$ matrices (or worse), but it's simply a matter of volume of calculations, no?

Comment: Now I try with Cramer's rule, but I was hoping to find a better way!

Comment: Cramer's rule is incredibly expensive! People are telling you that you should already know how to invert matrices that are not diagonal. Even the basic algorithm for this is vastly easier than Cramer. You should practice with 2x2 and 3x3 matrices before trying the 4x4. And just write down the full metric and invert.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your counting of unknowns and equations is incorrect. There are $10$ unknowns (inverse metric components) and $10$ equations. The second equation in your question can be split into $6$ independent equations ($3 \times 2$, for $i$ and $j$). The first equation is only the $00$ part, and you forgot to write the $0i$ part of $g_{\mu \nu}g^{\nu 0}=\delta^0_\mu$ by putting $\mu = i$, to give $g_{i \nu}g^{\nu 0}=\delta^0_i = 0$. This ($0 \mu$) equation are in total 4 independent equations. So you have $10$ equations and $10$ unknowns.

Anyway, you don't really need to worry about all these several equations. And it doesn't matter how complicated your metric is. These days you can use a Mathematica package and just invert the metric. I believe xAct (xCoba, in particular is what you would need) should have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I solved doing the following calculations up to second order (which is what I needed to do, actually). I started with
\begin{equation*}
(\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}+\delta g_{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{2}\delta^2g_{\mu\nu})(\bar{g}^{\nu\lambda}+A_1^{\nu\lambda}+B_1^{\nu\lambda})=\delta^\lambda_\mu,
\end{equation*}
where $\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}$ is diagonal. Up to second order I got an equation for $A_1^{\lambda\rho}$ and one for $B_1^{\lambda\rho}$, namely I have
\begin{equation}
A_1^{\lambda\rho}=-\delta g_{\mu\nu}\bar{g}^{\lambda\nu}\bar{g}^{\rho\mu}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
B_2^{\lambda\rho}=-\bar{g}^{\rho\mu}\delta g_{\mu\nu} A_1^{\nu\lambda}-\frac{1}{2}\bar{g}^{\rho\mu}\bar{g}^{\nu\lambda}\delta^2 g_{\mu\nu}.
\end{equation}
In this way I easily solved my problem and found the correct expression for the contravariant metric up to second order.